# Data with double quotes is not uploaded into BIG QUERY trough app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a problem wile uploading gsheet data into the big query through app script. the is look like GsheetData[image]

This is happening because of double quotes at 3rd line of comments, can anybody provide me the solution for this

```
var jobSpec = {
configuration: {
  load: {
    destinationTable: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId
    },
    allowJaggedRows: true,
    writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    allowQuotedNewlines: true,
    schema: {
      fields: [ 
        {name: 'User_id', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'Email', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'Comments', type: 'STRING'},
         ]
    }
  }
}
};

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  var MAX_ROWS = 50000;
   var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("test");
   var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   var csvdata = "";
   for (var row = 1; row < data.length && row < MAX_ROWS + 1; row++) {
     for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      var cell = data[row][col].toString();
      if (cell.indexOf(",") != -1) {
      csvdata += "\"" + cell + "\"";
       } else {
        csvdata += cell;
  }

  if (col < data[row].length - 1) {
    csvdata += ",";
  }
}
csvdata += "\r\n";

}
```

Thank you..!

Comment: Can you please update your question with relevant code snippet ?

Comment: Hi Mohammad please find the code

Comment: Where is the call to big query ? Which data are you sending to big query

Comment: var data = Utilities.newBlob(csvdata, "application/octet-stream");

  BigQuery.Jobs.insert(jobSpec, projectId, data);
}

function dailyUpload(){
  pushToBQ("test_env", "Sample_data_Set",'test_data_tab');
  
}

Comment: I am sending the data which is on the screen shot

Comment: I am getting "Data between close double quote (") and field separator" error

Comment: You may refer with this links [1](https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/24610691/valid+csv+filed+import+fails+with+data+between+close+double+quote+quot+and+field+separator+field+starts+with) and [2](https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/10429090/inserting+quotes+in+big+query). It stated that the proper way to encode a double quote in CSV is to put another double quote in front of it.

Comment: Hi abielita thanks for reply, but i want to fix it at app-script level not at the big query level and it is not possible to put double quotes on every comment, there are millions of comments may contain double quotes, i want to upload the data as it is how the user commented about the product

Comment: @kalyan4uonly How did you get on with your resolving your problem? Are you still looking for assistance?